# Rigging: Limiting motion on one axis to when the object is in a specific position on another

Tags: rigging

I have modeled a child's toy robot.  It has a wooden block body with some slits cut in it:

[image: body of the object]

The head is connected to the body by an elastic string, not shown, but the head sits like this:

[image: head on body]

So the first problem I'd like to solve is to constrain the head to only moving along the X axis when it is positioned at (or near) 0 on the Y axis, but also allow it to move on the Y axis when it is positioned at (or near) 0 on the X axis.

I have no idea at all how to put together drivers and or constraints to support this.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I've been struggling to figure this out with constraints alone, and think maybe it can't be done that way, and will require scripting to fully pull off, because there is a need for a collision condition to be checked once your object moves past a particular threshold, and then bring about a change in constraint behavior depending on whether the condition is true or false. I'm hoping someone else is able to weigh in on how to solve this, because I'm also interested in learning how it can be done.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.  I think I can do it with a driver that manages two location constraints, setting the influence of one when the head is on the x axis and the other when it is on the y axis, but I'm not having much luck with it so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my setup there are 3 bones, one controls the body, one controls the head and one marks the center loc of the head. Center and head are child of the body. Head bone has been rotated on x axis -90 degrees, to match world orientations, and has z loc locked.

Head bone has two limit loc constraints, one for X axis, one for Y axis.

Their influence is driven by two similar drivers.

The first driver has two variables, transform channel kind, evaluating Y loc of the head bone and Y loc of center bone.
I've named the variables with the same name of the bones, but they can have any name you want.

The expression says: absolute value of difference between Y loc of head and Y loc of center is > 0.1 (you can vary this value).

If the condition is true 1.0 is the output, if false 0.0.

The second driver is the same but controls limit Y loc, evaluating X loc.

Every constraint and driver has to be set in local space, in order to work even when the character is rotated, translated and scaled.

In the first limit loc constraint you can add a limit y loc from -1 to 1 (and the same in the second for X loc), in order to prevent the head going outside the body boundaries.

[image]

Comment: For other reasons I need the head bone to be rotated so it is vertical so I had to change the drivers to use Z instead of Y, but this works.  The bit I didn't think of was to have a stationary reference bone.  Thanks.  It gets a little trickier at the body boundaries, because the head has to switch to moving along the Z axis while constraining the X and Y positions; but with the reference bone I can work that out.